# Access to Piaggio MP3 engine

Tags: engine, scooter

Some help needed here.

I ride a Piaggio 250 mp3 scooter. After a few weeks of stalling at traffic lights, it finally refused to start engine at all. I've tried the garage but they didn't repair it properly.

I'd like to try the basics on the engine myself (valves cleaning, spark, etc), but my main problem is just opening and getting access to the engine itself. The user manual doesn't say anything about it, but its not obvious at all.

Any pdf, links, videos or forum you can recommend would greatly help.    Thanks in advance,            a.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official Piaggio service manual.

[Piaggio MP3 250 Shop Manual](https://absolutelyscooters.net/manuals/Piaggio_MP3250_Service_Manual.pdf)

Comment: @user3310782 Notice that this is a link to the *service* manual.  It is much different (and much more helpful) than the *owner's* manual.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski.  You can actually get something done with this manual.